# AttributeError: module 'networkx.utils.decorators' has no attribute 'py_random_state'

Tags: pycharm, attributes, networkx

I installed the Akonda package for a while, and then two days ago, I installed Networx simulator.
I run the first code related to Networkx through pycharm and it was successfully worked. However, the second day I tried to run the same code but the error below was shown up.

AttributeError: module 'networkx.utils.decorators' has no attribute 'py_random_state'

Even though, I just write "import networkx as nx", it still gets the same error.

I searched on this website and others to look for a solution and tried to do all the instructions to solve this issue, but it still doesn't work.
Can You help me to fix that